# .Net 6 use option pattern to read json file with int as key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, system.text.json, microsoft.extensions.configuration

I am trying to read a json file using a c# option pattern. However, I am running into a problem where a property of Dictionary<int, myClass> is not being mapped correctly unless I changed it the key to string like Dictionary<string, myClass>

This is my example json file: test.json

```
{
  "TestMap": [
    {
      "SenderID": "RIMC_EVAC_ZONES",
      "FeedType": null,
      "CategoryMappings": {
        "4": {
          "CategoryID": 4,
          "VccCategoryName": "Local Disaster",
          "ReiCategoryName": "Local Disaster",
          "SubcategoryMappings": {
            "177": [
              {
                "SubcategoryID": 177,
                "ParentCategoryID": 4,
                "VccSubcategoryName": "Evacuation",
                "ReiSubcategoryName": "Evacuation"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "SenderID": "EARLY_HURRICANE",
      "FeedType": null,
      "CategoryMappings": {
        "16": {
          "CategoryID": 16,
          "VccCategoryName": "Tropical Storm",
          "ReiCategoryName": "Tropical Storm",
          "SubcategoryMappings": null
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class Sender {
    public string SenderID { get; set; }
    public string FeedType { get; set; }
    
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(IntKeyDictionaryConverter))]    
    public Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping> CategoryMappings { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryMapping {
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string VccCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ReiCategoryName { get; set; }
    
    public Dictionary<int, List<SubcategoryMapping>> SubcategoryMappings { get; set; }
}

public class SubcategoryMapping
{
    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string VccSubcategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ReiSubcategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

How I register the page:

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("Properties/test.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
```

And How I called to retrive the data:

```
List<Sender> people = Configuration.GetSection("TestMap").Get<List<Sender>>();
```

**Problem:**:
with my current model, The variable "People" will have its CategoryMapping as null but will retrieve other information such as SenderID or FeedType correctly.

However, if I change the "CategoryingMappings" to `Dictionary<string, CategoryMapping>`, then it will be mapped correctly. Same thing happened to "SubcategoryMapping" property of CategoryMapping class.

What I have tried: I tried to write custom converter, but it didn't work and cause the conversion to fail

```
public class IntKeyDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping>>
{
    public override Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping>();
    
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return dictionary;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                int key = int.Parse(reader.GetString());
                reader.Read(); 
                CategoryMapping value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CategoryMapping>(ref reader, options);
                dictionary.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping> value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
    }
}
```

**What I need help with** : I want integer as key when read the json into my class object. How do I achieve that?

Comment: *However, if I change the "CategoryingMappings" to `Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping>`, then it will be mapped correctly.* Do you mean `Dictionary<string, CategoryMapping>` ?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos yes, thanks. edited my post for typo.

Comment: But I try your code in my project, everything works well, even the key is int type, It can map correctly.

Comment: @XinranShen what version of .net did you use? mine was 6.0

Comment: @XinranShen just tried with .Net 7 , it is working fine, but it is not working with .Net 6

Comment: Yes, But i don't find any introduction about this in .Net 7, Maybe you can post an issue on github about this.

Comment: @XinranShen I did, the issue was closed. I don't think they will make any update on this issue because it is fixed by .Net 7 already.

Comment: What .NET Core version are you using?

Comment: @dbc 6.0, it is working as intended in .Net 7

Comment: According to JSON's spec
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259
"An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
   pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
   boolean, null, object, or array."

i.e. json keys are always strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` **does not use System.Text.Json to deserialize JSON**.  Instead it manually parses the JSON to `IConfigurationSection` elements then binds those to POCOs using reflection.  None of this seems to be documented, so for confirmation you may check the [source code for `ConfigurationBinder`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs).

In the [.NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.22/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L446), the method `BindDictionary()` is used to bind to a dictionary.  It has a commented restriction on dictionary key types to `string` and enum types:

> ```
> private static void BindDictionary(
>    object dictionary,
>     [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicProperties)]
>     Type dictionaryType,
>     IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
> {
>     // IDictionary<K,V> is guaranteed to have exactly two parameters
>     Type keyType = dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
>     Type valueType = dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments[1];
>     bool keyTypeIsEnum = keyType.IsEnum;
>
>     if (keyType != typeof(string) && !keyTypeIsEnum)
>     {
>         // We only support string and enum keys
>         return;
>     }
> ```

In [.NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.11/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L508) an additional method `BindDictionaryInterface()` exists which contains logic (added via [PR #71609](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/71609)) that explicitly supports numeric keys:

> ```
> private static object? BindDictionaryInterface(
>     object? source,
>     [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicProperties)]
>     Type dictionaryType,
>     IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
> {
>     // IDictionary<K,V> is guaranteed to have exactly two parameters
>     Type keyType = dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
>     Type valueType = dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments[1];
>     bool keyTypeIsEnum = keyType.IsEnum;
>     bool keyTypeIsInteger =
>         keyType == typeof(sbyte) ||
>         keyType == typeof(byte) ||
>         keyType == typeof(short) ||
>         keyType == typeof(ushort) ||
>         keyType == typeof(int) ||
>         keyType == typeof(uint) ||
>         keyType == typeof(long) ||
>         keyType == typeof(ulong);
>
>     if (keyType != typeof(string) && !keyTypeIsEnum && !keyTypeIsInteger)
>     {
>         // We only support string, enum and integer (except nint-IntPtr and nuint-UIntPtr) keys
>         return null;
>     }
> ```

This explains why the `public Dictionary<int, CategoryMapping> CategoryMappings { get; set; }` property can be bound successfully only after moving to .NET 7.

If you cannot move to .NET 7 but still require the use of dictionaries with integer keys, then **as a workaround** you could use the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to wrap your integer dictionaries in `IDictionary<string, TValue>` surrogates.

First, define the following `IntegerDictionaryAdapter<TValue>` class:

```
public class IntegerDictionaryAdapter<TValue> : AdapterDictionary<int, string, TValue>
{
    static int ToInt(string value) => int.Parse(value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    static string ToString(int value) => value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

    public IntegerDictionaryAdapter() : base(new Dictionary<int, TValue>(), s => ToInt(s), i => ToString(i)) { }
    public IntegerDictionaryAdapter(IDictionary<int, TValue> dictionary) : base(dictionary, s => ToInt(s), i => ToString(i)) { }
}

public class AdapterDictionary<TKeyIn, TKeyOut, TValue> : IDictionary<TKeyOut, TValue>
{
    readonly IDictionary<TKeyIn, TValue> dictionary;
    readonly Func<TKeyIn, TKeyOut> mapKeyToOuter;
    readonly Func<TKeyOut, TKeyIn> mapKeyToInner;

    public AdapterDictionary(IDictionary<TKeyIn, TValue> dictionary, Func<TKeyOut, TKeyIn> mapKeyToInner, Func<TKeyIn, TKeyOut> mapKeyToOuter)
    {
        this.dictionary = dictionary ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
        this.mapKeyToInner = mapKeyToInner ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapKeyToInner));
        this.mapKeyToOuter = mapKeyToOuter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapKeyToOuter));
    }

    public IDictionary<TKeyIn, TValue> UnderlyingDictionary => dictionary;

    KeyValuePair<TKeyIn, TValue> MapItemToOuter(KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue> item) { return new KeyValuePair<TKeyIn, TValue>(mapKeyToInner(item.Key), item.Value); }
    KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue> MapItemFromOuter(KeyValuePair<TKeyIn, TValue> item) { return new KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue>(mapKeyToOuter(item.Key), item.Value); }
    public void Add(TKeyOut key, TValue value) { dictionary.Add(mapKeyToInner(key), value); }
    public bool ContainsKey(TKeyOut key) { return dictionary.ContainsKey(mapKeyToInner(key)); }
    public ICollection<TKeyOut> Keys => new CollectionAdapter<TKeyIn, TKeyOut>(() => dictionary.Keys, mapKeyToOuter, mapKeyToInner);
    public bool Remove(TKeyOut key) { return dictionary.Remove(mapKeyToInner(key)); }
    public bool TryGetValue(TKeyOut key, out TValue value) { return dictionary.TryGetValue(mapKeyToInner(key), out value); }
    public ICollection<TValue> Values { get { return dictionary.Values; } }

    public TValue this[TKeyOut key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[mapKeyToInner(key)]; }
        set { dictionary[mapKeyToInner(key)] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue> item) { dictionary.Add(MapItemToOuter(item)); }
    public void Clear() { dictionary.Clear(); }
    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue> item) { return dictionary.Contains(MapItemToOuter(item)); }
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)  => this.CopyToArray(array, arrayIndex);
    public int Count { get { return dictionary.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return dictionary.IsReadOnly; } }
    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue> item) { return dictionary.Remove(MapItemToOuter(item)); }
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKeyOut, TValue>> GetEnumerator() { return dictionary.Select(i => MapItemFromOuter(i)).GetEnumerator(); }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}

public abstract class CollectionAdapterBase<TIn, TOut, TCollection> : ICollection<TOut> 
    where TCollection : ICollection<TIn>
{
    readonly Func<TCollection> getCollection;
    readonly Func<TIn, TOut> toOuter;

    public CollectionAdapterBase(Func<TCollection> getCollection, Func<TIn, TOut> toOuter)
    {
        this.getCollection = getCollection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getCollection));
        this.toOuter = toOuter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toOuter));
    }

    protected TCollection Collection { get { return getCollection(); } }
    protected TOut ToOuter(TIn inner) { return toOuter(inner); }
    public abstract void Add(TOut item);
    public abstract void Clear();

    public virtual bool Contains(TOut item)
    {
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<TOut>.Default;
        foreach (var member in Collection)
            if (comparer.Equals(item, ToOuter(member)))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void CopyTo(TOut[] array, int arrayIndex) => this.CopyToArray(array, arrayIndex);
    public int Count { get { return Collection.Count; } }
    public abstract bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    public abstract bool Remove(TOut item);
    public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator() => Collection.Select(item => ToOuter(item)).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}

public class CollectionAdapter<TIn, TOut> : CollectionAdapterBase<TIn, TOut, ICollection<TIn>>
{
    readonly Func<TOut, TIn> toInner;

    public CollectionAdapter(Func<ICollection<TIn>> getCollection, Func<TIn, TOut> toOuter, Func<TOut, TIn> toInner)
        : base(getCollection, toOuter)
    {
        this.toInner = toInner ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toInner));
    }

    protected TIn ToInner(TOut outer) { return toInner(outer); }
    public override void Add(TOut item) => Collection.Add(ToInner(item));
    public override void Clear() => Collection.Clear();
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return Collection.IsReadOnly; } }
    public override bool Remove(TOut item) => Collection.Remove(ToInner(item));
    public override bool Contains(TOut item) => Collection.Contains(ToInner(item));
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    internal static void CopyToArray<TItem>(this IEnumerable<TItem> collection, TItem[] array, int arrayIndex) 
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(collection);  
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(array);   
        foreach (var item in collection)
            array[arrayIndex++] = item;
    }
}
```

Then modify your classes to use it as follows:

```
public class Sender {
    public string SenderID { get; set; }
    public string FeedType { get; set; }
    
    public IntegerDictionaryAdapter<CategoryMapping> CategoryMappings { get; set; } = new();
}

public class CategoryMapping {
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string VccCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ReiCategoryName { get; set; }
    
    public IntegerDictionaryAdapter<CategoryMapping> SubcategoryMappings { get; set; } = new();
}

public class SubcategoryMapping
{
    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string VccSubcategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ReiSubcategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

And now you will be able to bind your configuration data model in .NET 6 (and .NET 7 as well) as follows, using the `UnderlyingDictionary` property to access your integer-keyed dictionaries:

```
List<Sender> people = Configuration.GetSection("TestMap").Get<List<Sender>>();

people.First().CategoryMappings.UnderlyingDictionary.Add(10101, new CategoryMapping { CategoryID = 10101, VccCategoryName = "foo", ReiCategoryName = "bar" });
```

(Honestly however I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.)

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qSP1TY).

Comment: Thank you so much. We ended up change the data structure a bit to not use dictionary, but this is such an insightful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The C# Configuration extensions use `System.Text.Json` to deserialize, which by default is fairly strict about types. I know there are some "Web Defaults" [JsonSerializerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-6-0#web-defaults-for-jsonserializeroptions) that allow reading numbers from strings, but I don't see an obvious way of how to pass the options to the configuration reader... But if there is a way, that's how you might solve this.</s>

Otherwise, a workaround is to deserialize this JSON by hand, and *don't* use the options pattern.

```csharp
public record Root(List<Sender> TestMap)
...
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(File.OpenRead("Properties/test.json"), options);
```

Comment: I believe System.Text.Json should support integer as key for deserialization since 5.0. I am currently using 8.0, it is a bit weird that it would be the problem. Maybe time to write up an issue page for their github?

Comment: *The C# Configuration extensions use System.Text.Json to deserialize* -- this is false.  The code for `icrosoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.ConfigurationBinder` is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs), and you can check that neither System.Text.Json nor Json.NET are used.  Instead binding is done manually via reflection from parsed `IConfiguration` elements.

Comment: @ZpfSysn - You are correct that System.Text.Json has supported integer keys for since .NET 5, see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-next-for-system-text-json/#new-features) for confirmation.  The problem is that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder does not use System.Text.Json.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I assumed wrongly. Thanks @dbc for going deep on this.

Comment: With this approach you would need to add a top-level wrapper class such as `public record Root(List<Sender> TestMap)`.